# How to use isVerified()

Tags: vuejs2, feathersjs, email-verification

Created email-verification that takes a user to a verification page. Code to change isVerified is verifyUser.vue

```
this.verifyToken({
     action: "verifySignupLong",
     value 
})
```

Where value is the Token
In users on the server have isVerified() on before->get and find

But when verifyToken is ran it tries to find the user and fails at isVerified. How do I get verifiedToken changed from false to true before running verifySignupLong

Answer (score 0):

users does not verify email-verification. Authmanagement does.